# How to extend only one parent?

Tags: php, oop

Let's say I have 2 classes

```
class BaseClass {
   ...
}

class SomeClass extends BaseClass {

}
```

now I want to create third class, that will only extend SomeClass, but not get anything from BaseClass. Is that even possible?

I'm writing Selenium tests with webdriver and want to check data from Selenium against DB or WebServices, but don't want to load the whole framework, just some of our libraries

Comment: Can you clarify "don't want to load the whole framework, just some of our libraries" because it sounds like your inheritance graph is broken.

Comment: Class based includes (which might be what you're looking for) are possible with [*traits*](http://php.net/traits). No idea if they make sense in your case, but what you're looking for directly does not exist in PHP.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. That's not how Inheritance works. A class inheriting from SomeClass will always inherit all it's properties and methods, including those of SomeClass inherited from BaseClass. You can limit access to them through Visibility, but only from private over protected to public, not the other way round, e.g. you can loose visibility, but not tighten it.

See the chapters in the PHP Manual about Inheritance and Visibility:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

---

Another option would be to use some sort of Facade around an instance of SomeClass to control the access to properties and methods accessible in SomeClass, e.g. assuming your SomeClass has a method foo() and inherits bar() from BaseClass, you could do

```
class LimitedAccess
{
     private $instance;

     public function __construct(SomeClass $someClass)
     {
          $this->instance = $someClass
     }

     public function foo()
     {
         return $this->instance->foo;
     }
}
```

and then you can funnel all access through this Facade effectively preventing access to BaseClass::bar(). Note, that this will not change the inheritance hierarchy in any way. It just controls access.

Comment: I know how inheritance works, just hoped there will be some way to stop inheriting :)

thanx anyway

Answer (score 2):

Think about as Human...
You have mother and she has mother... 
You cant be son of your mother without being grandson of your grandmother..

same is at PHP

when Class extends other its AWAYS his child...

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that if you put a `PROTECTED` access modifier on the method in `BaseClass` that you want to be restricted to be called from the `Third` class..

Comment: but that would also restrict SomeClass to access those methods, which is not what I need

Comment: @TomasJancik:No it would not because your SomeClass is already inheriting the BaseClass which fulfills the criteria to access the Protected modifier prefixed function..

Comment: @RahulRanjan anything protected in Base will be protected in the child classes, so Foo extending Bar extending Base will have all protected members of Base as well.

Comment: @Gordon No,if the class B inherits class A,then all protected members will be visible to B class only but not in class C even though class C inherits class B.For accessing the class A PROTECTED methods,class C will have to inherit the class A directly..

Comment: @RahulRanjan you might want to read up on that again because http://codepad.org/s5gNitt1